# How to mark all SYSLIB warnings as errors

Tags: compiler-errors, msbuild, warnings, compiler-warnings, .net-5

I'm porting huge project from net framework to net5 and this brings tons of warnings. I want to make all warnings starting with `SYSLIB` to be an error.
One possible solution is to list all warnings inside `WarnAsError` but this is too much to write for such a simple task and also if another warning appear (e.g. syslib00013) with newer version it's gonna be warning, not error.

```xml
<WarnAsError>($WarnAsError);SYSLIB0001;SYSLIB0002;etc</WarnAsError>
```

Writing `<WarnAsError>true</WarnAsError>` is not an option

Attempt to write `<WarningsAsErrors>$(WarnAsError);SYSLIB</WarningsAsErrors>` didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

After some time I've found nice and clean way to do it.

I had to write `UsingTask`

```xml
  <UsingTask TaskName="ExpandRanges"
             TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"
             >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Ranges ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
      <Result ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System.Linq" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
     <![CDATA[
        const string prefixName = "Prefix";

        var list = new List<ITaskItem>(Ranges.Length);

        foreach (var range in Ranges)
        {
          string include = range.ToString();
          string prefix = range.GetMetadata(prefixName);
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
          {
              Log.LogWarning($"Metadata {prefixName} was not found in {include} and will be ignored");
              continue;
          }

          if (include.All(char.IsDigit))
          {
              list.Add(new TaskItem(prefix + include));
          }
          else if (include.Split('-') is { Length: 2 } splitted)
          {
              int start = int.Parse(splitted[0]);
              int stop = int.Parse(splitted[1]);

              for (int i = start; i < stop + 1; i++)
              {
                  list.Add(new TaskItem($"{prefix}{i:0000}"));
              }
          }
          else
          {
              Log.LogWarning($"{include} have incorrect format and will be ignored");
          }
        }

        Result = list.ToArray();
]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

And `Target`

```xml
  <Target Name="ExpandWarningsAsErrorsRange"
          BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"
          Inputs="@(WarningsAsErrorsRange)"
          Outputs="$(WarningsAsErrors)"
          >
    <ExpandRanges Ranges="@(WarningsAsErrorsRange)">
      <Output ItemName="_WarnRange" TaskParameter="Result" />
    </ExpandRanges>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);@(_WarnRange)</WarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

Both these things should be located in `Directory.Build.targets` and projects need only include specific warnings

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <WarningsAsErrorsRange Include="0000-0002" Prefix="SYSLIB" />
    <WarningsAsErrorsRange Include="0006" Prefix="SYSLIB" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This solution have some flaws like it doesn't support `Exclude` in ItemGroup but it's enough for me.